# show modal for booking in react big calendar when click on slot and keep book button in empty slot

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-modal, react-big-calendar

I am trying to achieve **modal** in react big calendar when I click on empty slot. My by default view is **week**. This is my code.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        events: [
            {
                id: 1,
                start: new Date(moment().add(-1, "days")),
                end: new Date(),
                title: "Learn Laravel"
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                start: new Date(),
                end: new Date(moment().add(-3, "days")),
                title: "Learn PHP"
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                start: new Date(),
                end: new Date(moment().add(-2, "days")),
                title: "Learn Database"
            }
        ]
    };
}

slotSelected(slotInfo) {
    console.log(slotInfo);
    **I want pop-up/modal here **

}

eventSelected(eventInfo) {
    console.log(eventInfo);
}

render() {

    return <MyCalendar allEvents={this.state.events} eventSelected={this.eventSelected}
                       slotSelected={this.slotSelected}/>
}


<div id="mycalendar" style={calendarStyle}>
    <Calendar
        defaultDate={new Date()}
        defaultView="week"
        events={props.allEvents}
        style={{height: "50vh", width: "60vh"}}
        selectable={true}
        onSelectSlot={props.slotSelected}
        onSelectEvent={props.eventSelected}
    />

</div>
```

Now I want a modal to show when I click on empty slot. If possible I want create a book button in the slot. I am using bootstrap modal in my application.I need help on this. There is comment in the code where I want modal. Thanks

Comment: since you are executing parent class `slotSelected` function so define any variable as true on which you can open a Modal on either parent component or child component by passing the same variable.
something like 
```slotSelected = () => {
    this.setState({ modelOpen: true });
}
```